# D3 Sunburst diagram depth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, sunburst-diagram

I'm working with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9WnB/64/) of a sunburst-diagram. What I'm trying to get is to remove the outer layer, the one that displays SKU information of a category, and only have Group and Category layers. I've never worked with D3 so my guess is tree depth is a problem but I couldn't figure out which part of the code to edit so I tried alternative approach.

What I hoped would solve the problem was to remove all JSON data that is used in the outer layer. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdqbgeoa/1/) show the result. Unfortunately, it seems the code isn't "smart" enough to fill the blanks/ adjust the slices width. And since I'm no smarter either, I come to you for help.

Due to the character limit I'm posting only parts of the code that I think are relevant.

Original data structure:

```
var data1 = JSON.parse('[
{
"group":["Books","Arts","ZD111111"],"current":{"count":37}
},{
"group":["Electronics","Audio","ZD111288"],"current":{"count":36}
},{
"group":["Electronics","Camcorders","ZD111301"],"current":{"count":35}
}, ... ]);
```

Edited data structure:

```
var data1 = JSON.parse('[
{
"group":["Books","Arts"],"current":{"count":37}
},{
"group":["Electronics","Audio"],"current":{"count":36}
},{
"group":["Electronics","Camcorders"],"current":{"count":35}
}, ... ]);
```

Sunburst chart:

```
treePath = ["group","category"],

var controller = function(data, progress) {
    if(progress === 100) {
        data2 = $.extend(true, [], data2);
        var flatData = [];
        data.map(function(d) {
            var item = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < treePath.length; i++) {
                item[treePath[i]] = d.group[i];
            }
            //item.size = d3.selectAll("input").filter(function (d) { return this.checked; }).attr("value") === "count" ? d.current.count : d.current.metrics.price.sum;
            item.size = d.current.count; // always show count data            
            item.model = d;
            return flatData.push(item);
        });
        flatData.forEach(function(d) {
            d.model.group = d.model.group[d.model.group.length - 1];
        });

        var treeData = genJSON(flatData, treePath.slice(0, treePath.length - 1));
        d3.select("#vis")
            .datum(treeData)
            .call(chart);
    }
};

function genJSON(csvData, groups) {

    var genGroups = function(data) {
        return _.map(data, function(element, index) {
            return { name : index, children : element };
        });
    };

    var nest = function(node, curIndex) {
        if (curIndex === 0) {
            node.children = genGroups(_.groupBy(csvData, groups[0]));
            _.each(node.children, function (child) {
                nest(child, curIndex + 1);
            });
        }
        else {
            if (curIndex < groups.length) {
                node.children = genGroups(
                    _.groupBy(node.children, groups[curIndex])
                );
                _.each(node.children, function (child) {
                    nest(child, curIndex + 1);
                });
            }
        }
        return node;
    };
    return nest({}, 0);
}

function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
}

function sunburst() {
    var instance = this,
        svg = null,
        timestamp = new Date().getTime(),
        widgetHeight = 600,
        widgetWidth = 600,
        widgetSize = 'large',
        margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 10},
        width = widgetWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = widgetHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
        y = d3.scale.pow().exponent(1),
        pgColor = d3.scale.ordinal().range([
            {"family": "Blue", 1: "#0000CC", 2: "#0099FF", 3: "#CCFFFF"},
            {"family": "Orange", 1: "#FF6600", 2: "#FFCC00", 3: "#FFFFCC"},
            {"family": "Green", 1: "#009900", 2: "#99CC33", 3: "#CCFF99"},
            {"family": "Red", 1: "#FF3333", 2: "#FF9999", 3: "#FFCCCC"},
            {"family": "Purple", 1: "#CC0099", 2: "#FF66CC", 3: "#FFCCFF"},
            {"family": "Grey", 1: "#7b7b7b", 2: "#999999", 3: "#eeeeee"}]),
        luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
            .domain([0, 1e6])
            .clamp(true)
            .range([90, 20]),
        i = 0,
        partition = d3.layout.partition().sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name || a[treePath[treePath.length - 1]], b.name || b[treePath[treePath.length - 1]])}),
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
            .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
            .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.y ? y(d.y) : d.y); })
            .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function(data) {
            instance.data = data;
            width = widgetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
            height = widgetHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

            y.range([0, radius]);

            // Select the svg element, if it exists.
            svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

            var gEnter = svg.enter()
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "600")
                .attr("height", "600")
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "main-group");

            gEnter.append("defs")
                .append("clipPath")
                .attr("id", "clip-" + timestamp)
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0);

            var sunburstGroup = gEnter.append("g")
                .attr("class", "sunburst-area")
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "sunburst-group");


            sunburstGroup.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "sunburst-background")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .style("fill", "white");

            // Update the inner group dimensions.
            var g = svg.select("g.main-group")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + margin.left) + "," + (height / 2 + margin.top) + ")");

            g.select(".sunburst-background")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            partition.value(function(d) { return d.size; })
            .nodes(data)
            .forEach(function(d) {
                d.key = key(d);
            });

            var path = g.select(".sunburst-group").selectAll(".sunArcs")
                .data(partition.nodes(data), function(d) { return d.key; });

            path.enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "sunArcs")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    if(d.depth === 0) return "#fff";
                    var color = pgColor(d.key.split(".")[0]);
                    return color[d.depth];
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 0)
                .on("click", click)
                .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
                .each(function(d) {
                    this.x0 = d.x;
                    this.dx0 = d.dx;
                });

            path.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                .attrTween("d", arcTweenUpdate);

            path.exit()
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attrTween("d", arcTweenUpdate)
                .style("fill-opacity", 0)
                .remove();

            function key(d) {
                var k = [], p = d;
                while (p.depth) k.push(p.name || p[treePath[treePath.length - 1]]), p = p.parent;
                return k.reverse().join(".");
            }    

            function click(d) {
                path.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attrTween("d", arcTween(d));
            }

            function getParents(d) {
                var parents = [], p = d;
                while (p.depth >= 1) {
                    parents.push(p);
                    p = p.parent;
                }
                return parents;
            }

            function mouseover(d) {
                if(d.depth === 0) return;
                var parentNodes = getParents(d);
                 // Fade all the arcs.
                d3.selectAll(".sunArcs")
                .style("opacity", 0.3);

                // Highlight all arcs in path    
                d3.selectAll(".sunArcs").filter(function(d){
                    return (parentNodes.indexOf(d) >= 0);
                })
                .style("opacity", 1);


                // Initialize variables for tooltip
                var group = d.name || d[treePath[treePath.length - 1]],
                    valueFormat = d3.format(",.0f"),
                    textMargin = 5,
                    popupMargin = 10,
                    opacity = 1,
                    fill = d3.select(this).style("fill"),
                    hoveredPoint = d3.select(this),
                    pathEl = hoveredPoint.node(),

                // Fade the popup stroke mixing the shape fill with 60% white
                    popupStrokeColor = d3.rgb(
                        d3.rgb(fill).r + 0.6 * (255 - d3.rgb(fill).r),
                        d3.rgb(fill).g + 0.6 * (255 - d3.rgb(fill).g),
                        d3.rgb(fill).b + 0.6 * (255 - d3.rgb(fill).b)
                    ),

                // Fade the popup fill mixing the shape fill with 80% white
                    popupFillColor = d3.rgb(
                        d3.rgb(fill).r + 0.8 * (255 - d3.rgb(fill).r),
                        d3.rgb(fill).g + 0.8 * (255 - d3.rgb(fill).g),
                        d3.rgb(fill).b + 0.8 * (255 - d3.rgb(fill).b)
                    ),

                // The running y value for the text elements
                    y = 0,
                // The maximum bounds of the text elements
                    w = 0,
                    h = 0,
                    t,
                    box,
                    rows = [], p = d,
                    overlap;

                var hoverGroup = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).append("g").attr("class", "hoverGroup");

                // Add a group for text   
                t = hoverGroup.append("g");
                // Create a box for the popup in the text group
                box = t.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "tooltip");


                    if(!isInt(d.value)) {
                        valueFormat = d3.format(",.2f");
                    }


                while (p.depth >= 1) {
                    rows.push(treePath[p.depth - 1] + ": " + (p.name || p[treePath[treePath.length - 1]]));
                    p = p.parent;
                }
                rows.reverse();
                rows.push("Volume: " + valueFormat(d.value));

                t.selectAll(".textHoverShapes").data(rows).enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "textHoverShapes")
                    .text(function (d) { return d; })
                    .style("font-size", 14);

                // Get the max height and width of the text items
                t.each(function () {
                    w = (this.getBBox().width > w ? this.getBBox().width : w);
                    h = (this.getBBox().width > h ? this.getBBox().height : h);
                });

                // Position the text relatve to the bubble, the absolute positioning
                // will be done by translating the group
                t.selectAll("text")
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", function () {
                        // Increment the y position
                        y += this.getBBox().height;
                        // Position the text at the centre point
                        return y - (this.getBBox().height / 2);
                    });

                // Draw the box with a margin around the text
                box.attr("x", -textMargin)
                    .attr("y", -textMargin)
                    .attr("height", Math.floor(y + textMargin) - 0.5)
                    .attr("width", w + 2 * textMargin)
                    .attr("rx", 5)
                    .attr("ry", 5)
                    .style("fill", popupFillColor)
                    .style("stroke", popupStrokeColor)
                    .style("stroke-width", 2)
                    .style("opacity", 0.95);

                // Move the tooltip box next to the line point
                t.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + " , " + 10 + ")");
            }

            // Mouseleave Handler
            function mouseleave(d) {
                d3.selectAll(".sunArcs")
                .style("opacity", 1);
                d3.selectAll(".hoverGroup")
                .remove();
            }            

            // Interpolate the scales!
            function arcTween(d) {
                xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
                yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
                yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
                return function(d, i) {
                    return i 
                    ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
                    : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
                };
            }

            function arcTweenUpdate(a) {
                var updateArc = this;
                var i = d3.interpolate({x: updateArc.x0, dx: updateArc.dx0}, a);
                return function(t) {
                    var b = i(t);
                    updateArc.x0 = b.x;
                    updateArc.dx0 = b.dx;
                    return arc(i(t));
                };
            }            
        });
    }
```

I'll accept either solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple objects with same groups after you removed SKU group.
Example:

```
{
    "group": ["Jewelry", "Diamonds"],
    "current": {
        "count": 26
    }
}

{
    "group": ["Jewelry", "Diamonds"],
    "current": {
        "count": 28
    }
}
```

You should either correct the data or sum these entries. I have updated your fiddle to test after aggregation entries with same groups and it looks fine now (https://jsfiddle.net/zwg31n7h/):

```
var oldData = _.find(flatData, function(f){
                var found = true;
                _.each(treePath, function(t){
                    if(f[t] !== item[t]) {
                        found = false;
                    }
                });
                return found;
            });
            if(oldData) {
                oldData.size += item.size;
                oldData.model.current.count += item.size;
            } else {
                flatData.push(item);
            }
```

Comment: I'm glad the script is "smarter" than me. I completely missed the fact that losing the SKU group creates duplicates. :D Thanks.